# DNS Server Bind9, Want to Map host IP with Port to Hostname

Tags: networking, server, dns, bind, port-forwarding

I want to set up DNS server which named **"home.local"** for local usage to mapping IP and port to specific hostname. I already set up DNS server with Bind9 on Ubuntu 15.10 ,and it working smoothly with IP with defualt port (80). Several of my servers (Odoo, Emby, FileServer, Mail Server) are using different ports such as 8096, 8069, 5000. I cannot change the port of Servers since it's is default port or security recommended port and cannot be changed, So I come to trouble now. To clearly explain, example, I have server IP 192.168.100.100, it is Streaming Server of Emby which run on port 8096. I don't want to change the port since it may cause some problems and number of Servers are lot, I cannot do anything router related to port forwarding. I want to use Name instead of IP by helping of DNS for that Server, example Hostname "***movie*.home.local**" so if I type **movie.home.local** it will map to **192.168.100.100:8096** not ***movie.home.local:8096*** because it's not a kind of good practice and hard to remember port for users.  As I read around different site, They said DNS can be mapping only IP to hostname not port. but I see in Godaddy Hosting they can do it. So any way to add Edit DNS server to make it work, or Any solution.

Hope to find solution here since it's necessary for me.
Thank

Comment: You cannot do this with Bind9 or any DNS on its own.  DNS only has an effect on the hostname to IP resolution - not the port.  It would be more advanced than just DNS to get this type of thing set up.  (I may post something useful tomorrow as an answer after I have gotten some sleep...)

Comment: this Streaming Server, what's the URL structure that you use to access it?  (An example link would be fine, because depending on what you're trying to stream and how, may influence my answer)

Comment: Thank for your guiding. Mainly Server that I want to map is Streaming Server = 192.168.1.1:8096 and ERP (Odoo Server) = 192.168.1.254:8069, I have few more servers ,but the 2 above is compulsory. Hope to hear from you back.

Comment: that doesn't answer my question.  How do you *access* the data on these servers?  Web interfaces listening on these ports?

Comment: Yes, for accessing 2 above Servers, it has two different types. For Streaming Server 192.168.1.1:8096, I access it by app in mobile (IOS, Android, IPad) platform and for PC , access it by typing IP and port in browsers (It's a kind of web app). For Odoo 192.168.1.254:8069, accessing by typing IP and port in browsers or web interface (It's also kind of web app).

Comment: You need NGNIX or Apache HTTP server as a proxy server for forwarding http requests to appropriate application -> which listens particular port